# sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice: bug, error or what?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm using `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` to build select elements in a form. This is how I'm using:

```
// Fill maquinaemisorid
$this->widgetSchema['maquinaemisorid'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'SdrivingMaquina', 'add_empty' => 'Seleccione una Máquina', 'table_method' => 'fillChoice'));

// Fill idoperador
$this->widgetSchema['idoperador'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'SdrivingOperador', 'add_empty' => 'Seleccione un Operador', 'table_method' => 'fillChoice'));

// Fill idturno
$this->widgetSchema['idturno'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'SdrivingTurno', 'add_empty' => 'Seleccione un Turno', 'table_method' => 'fillChoice'));
```

For the first widget all is fine and values are taken from DB as should be but for the second one and the third is not working. As you may notice I'm calling a method `fillChoice` in all widgets `table_method`. This is the code for the three:

`SdrivingMaquinaTable.class.php`

```
public function fillChoice() {
    $id_empresa = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingMaquina')->createQuery('a')->where('a.idempresa = ?', $id_empresa)->execute();
}
```

`SdrivingOperadorTable.class.php`

```
public function fillChoice() {
    $id_empresa = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingOperador')->createQuery('a')->where('a.idempresa = ?', $id_empresa)->execute();
}
```

`SdrivingTurno.class.php`

```
public function fillChoice() {
    $id_empresa = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingTurno')->createQuery('a')->where('a.idempresa = ?', $id_empresa)->execute();
}
```

The method is the same always just changes the table used for each class. I check the generated queries and all are fine and if I run each on phpMyAdmin for example more than one value is fetched altough in `idoperador` and `idturno` just the latest is rendered. This is a very rare behavior and I can't find the error or mistake so I need some help or advice here.

As an adition I tried this in `SdrivingRegistrosEmisoresForm.class.php` (this is where the widgets are being generated):

```
$id_empresa = $this->current_user->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
$choices_operador = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingOperador')->createQuery('a')->where('a.idempresa = ?', $id_empresa)->execute();

$this->widgetSchema['idoperador'] = new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $choices_operador));
```

And this way works fine but the `id` for each item fetched isn't right meaning:

```
id      item     real_id
0       Item1    2
1       Item2    16
2       Item4    3
```

I talked about this in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179725/sfwidgetformdoctrinechoice-renders-only-one-value-but-query-returns-5-values) but didn't get any answer, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in *sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice*, if option *table_method* returns a collection like your methods, it renders choices with options *key_method* and *method*. By default , they are respectively *getPrimaryKey()* and *__toString()*.

Can we check you schema.yml and the __toString() ?

As for your last example the option *choices* of *sfWidgetFormSelect* should be an array an not a *Doctrine_Collection*